# How can I simplify my google app script I copy/pasted multiple times for each of my different ranges?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, simplify

I already searched stackoverflow for a solution, but to no success. It seems I don't know how to "name" my problem correctly ...

I found two functions for my Google sheet that help me count successes and losses at work. They work wonderfully.

**plus1() adds +1 to a value in A1**

```
function plus1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var yesCount = ss.getRange("A1");
var yesAdd = yesCount.getValue();
yesCount.setValue(yesAdd+1);
}
```

**minus1() subtracts 1 to a value in A1:**

```
function minus1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var yesCount = ss.getRange("A1");
var yesAdd = yesCount.getValue();
yesCount.setValue(yesAdd-1);
}
```

**I edited my question for clarification**
I increment or decrement the cells individually, not all at once. For example: This morning I incremented 1 to cell A1. This afternoon I decremented 3 to cell A1.
Also, I attached those scripts to a custom menu bar with ui.createMenu.

**My problem:** I use 6x the same script only with different ranges:

```
1) plus1A() with Range A1
2) plus1B() with Range A2
3) plus1C() with Range A3
4) minus1A() with Range A1
5) minus1B() with Range A2
6) minus1C() with Range A3
```

**My questions:** Isn't there a way to simplify the script so I don't end up with 6 times the same code, that only differ in ranges?

Many thanks for your valuable time!
Ron

Comment: How are you calling them? Are you attaching them to buttons?

Comment: I call them by clicking on a menu bar ( ui.createMenu('Add+1')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind to have four or six or any number of separate functions and all you need is to make them simpler, here is the possible way:

```
# six functions for custom menu

function a1_plus()  { change('a1',  1) }
function a1_minus() { change('a1', -1) }

function a2_plus()  { change('a2',  1) }
function a2_minus() { change('a2', -1) }

function a3_plus()  { change('a3',  1) }
function a3_minus() { change('a3', -1) }


# inner function

function change(range, value) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r  = ss.getRange(range);
  var v  = r.getValue();
  r.setValue(v + value);
}
```

Comment: Perfect Yuri!! Thank you so much! Your script only has  1/3 of the characters my script has ... yours looks so much simpler - Thank you again Yuri!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably set it up as an increment function and a separate decrement function and just use the current active range.  So you would have to select the cell you wish to increment or decrement and push either increment or decrement

```
function increment() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getActiveCell().setValue(ss.getActiveCell().getValue() + 1);
}

function decrement() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getActiveCell().setValue(ss.getActiveCell().getValue() - 1);
}
```

If you use a sidebar for common repetitive functions like this it's a lot more convenient than using a drop down menu.

Comment: Thank you. It won't work for me because I can't use the current active range.

Comment: By the time I need to increment or decrement I am in row 936 and the active cell is in column C

Comment: I don't understand but that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the range, get the range  values, loop through the values add one to each value, then set the new values to your initial range, like so:

```js
const plusOne = () => {
  const range = "A1:A5";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const yesRange = ss.getRange(range);
  const yesValues = yesRange.getValues();
  const newValues = yesValues.map(row => row.map(cell => +cell + 1));
  yesRange.setValues(newValues);
}
```

**UPDATED**
As per your comment below, use a parameter:

```js
const plusOne = range => {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const yesRange = ss.getRange(range);
  const yesValues = yesRange.getValues();
  const newValues = yesValues.map(row => row.map(cell => +cell + 1));
  yesRange.setValues(newValues);
}
```

This will work with a single cell or a range of cells

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry! I want to add or substract to the cells individually, not all at once. For example: This morning I added 1 to cell A1. This afternoon I added 1 to cell A3. I am sorry that I wasn't clear.

Comment: In that case you probably want to pass the cell range as a function parameter and call it like so: `plusOne('A1')`

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. I would have to define the range whenever I use your script, but then I could just work with my script and change the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

For example with this script you can increment or decrement selected cell by clicking on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Nupmpad -</kbd> buttons respectively:

```
!NumpadAdd::
send ^c
sleep, 50
Clipboard := Clipboard + 1
send ^v
return

!NumpadSub::
send ^c
sleep, 50
Clipboard := Clipboard - 1
send ^v
return
```

Comment: Thank you Yuri. Unfortunately I cannot download software on my computer at work.